# Spy on method call on button click with Jest/Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test in method was called on button click. I have following code:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Btn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleClick = this.toggleClick.bind(this);
  }


  toggleClick() {
    const { onClick } = this.props;
    onClick();
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <button
        className="btn"
        onClick={this.toggleClick}
      >
        <div />
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

I wrote such a test to test if onToggleClick was called:

```
test('test button click', () => {
   const wrapper = shallow(<Btn {...props} />);

    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    const spyOnClick = jest.spyOn(instance, 'toggleClick');

    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');

    expect(spyOnClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

but what I have in console output is

```
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

I do not understand where is my mistake or what I did wrong. Can somebody help?

Comment: I don't know if this could be the problem, but you are binding a method that doesn't exist. You should bind 'toggleClick' instead of 'onToggleClick'.

Comment: edited, this is not a problem

Comment: You don't need to spyOn anything, pass a test double function into the props and make sure *that* gets called. Test behaviour (passed callback is invoked), not implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `jest.spyOn` before shallow rendering the component.

E.g.

`index.jsx`

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class Btn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleClick = this.toggleClick.bind(this);
  }

  toggleClick() {
    const { onClick } = this.props;
    onClick();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button className="btn" onClick={this.toggleClick}>
        <div />
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

`index.spec.jsx`:

```js
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Btn from './';

describe('59481051', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('test button click', () => {
    const props = { onClick: jest.fn() };
    const spyOnClick = jest.spyOn(Btn.prototype, 'toggleClick');
    const wrapper = shallow(<Btn {...props} />);
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(spyOnClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(props.onClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/59481051/index.spec.jsx (12.053s)
  59481051
    ✓ test button click (15ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.jsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.703s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59481051